# AJAX from PhoneGap - Cross-Domain Concerns?

Tags: ajax, cordova, cross-domain

I want to communicate via AJAX calls with a back-end server from a PhoneGap application.

Is there a way to associate the PhoneGap application with a domain that I own so that the requests don't all have to use CORS or JSONP?

If not, is it preferable to use CORS or JSONP for these AJAX requests from PhoneGap?

Comment: The HTML code that makes up your app will not be "hosted" on any server but will instead be packaged as a real native app, so there are no "cross domain" issues. There is a whitelist though that blocks requests from your app to the outside for security purposes - you'll have to add your back-end server to this whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to be concerned about cross domain requests from a mobile device. They somehow don't matter. Your device can make requests to any site's JSON service just fine. If, however, you want to test locally on your PC prior to building and deploying to a device, you will need to use JSONP. I always use JSONP for that reason.

Comment: I think you can test locally if you host a server on your machine without JSONP. Something like node server or Uniserver would work where you can just spin up an HTTP server that hosts your /www/ folder and make requests to your IP from the app - just have to change the `href` attributes.

Comment: @MBillau you are correct. I should have said if you want to test locally with no changes to your code then you need jsonp.

Comment: I wonder if you could keep all of the links as relative URLs, host your project's /www/ folder on your server, and change the entry point in your app (for example, in AndroidManifest.xml) to the IP address...that way you only have to change one URL when testing...

Comment: Or you could just use JSONP and call it a day :)